# Interface Methods vs Data Objects

Tags: interfaces, composition, ui, properties

Building a UI editor for Android and basically there are interfaces such as this:

```kotlin
interface Item {
    fun decorate()
    fun translate(x: Int, y: Int)
    fun rotate(rotation: Float)
    fun scale(scale: Float)
    fun select(value: Boolean)
}
```

also has been extended with interfaces like so:

```kotlin
interface Removable {
    fun remove()
}
```

Meaning that the `View` that is an `Item` that can be removed implements both `Item` (obviously) and `Removable`.

But in addition to these, for the `View`s that have unique properties, such as text properties, this has been created:

```kotlin
interface Updatable {
    fun update(data: Any)
}
```

This takes some data class that can be interpreted after type-checking to update/modify the `View`.

To be more clear, the implementation of `Item`, `BasicItem` will have the target `View` set via a setter method.

This means, a `RemovableTextItem` will implement `Item`, `Removable` and `Updatable` via delegation where one of the delegated class for `Item` interface would be `BasicItem` and for the other interfaces similar implementations would be delegated to.

The problem in this approach is the verbosity, and addition of some methods to `Item` now seems like a burden. Notice that inheritance here, is being avoided deliberately in practice of composition lending more to this issue.

Would you suggest shrinking all of this down to an interface `Item` with method `update` only that takes `ItemProperties` data class which would be interpreted by the class that implements it?

Comment: Last two paragraphs need to be paraphrased to make them more understandable. Maybe itemized, shorter sentences.

Comment: if all items are removable and updatable why not have `Item` implement/extend `Removable` and `Updatable`?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova is this clear enough now?

Comment: @zzzzBov well, all items are not removable or updatable, if they were for now, what if later one method had to be removed or separated, wouldn't all others break?